# CrossCompile jrxtx with yocto

Tags: java, serial-port, yocto, autotools

I'm trying to crosscompile jrxtx library (https://github.com/openmuc/jrxtx) using a yocto toolchain but it fails.

first 
`source /opt/poky/environment-setup-cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`

then
`cd /home/peppe/projects/rxtx/jrxtx/native && ./BUILD.sh`

I had to hand modify config.status to remove some errors on mv and rm, nevertheless i get

`/bin/bash /home/peppe/projects/rxtx/jrxtx/native/libtool --mode=link arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a8 --sysroot=/opt/poky/sysroots/cortexa8t2hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D__need_timespec -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -lpthread -release 2.2pre1 -o librxtxSerial.la -rpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64 /home/peppe/projects/rxtx/jrxtx/native/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/SerialImp.lo; \
fi;                                                                                                \
)
/bin/bash: line 2: cd: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /home/peppe/projects/rxtx/jrxtx/native/libtool: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /home/peppe/projects/rxtx/jrxtx/native/libtool: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: /home/peppe/projects/rxtx/jrxtx/native/libtool: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:756: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.la] Error 127`

Even it it seems to launch the correct compiler `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc` it tries to cd into `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` and obviously things gets mad...

Comment: It seems your SDK is wrongly installed as it cannot found your binaries. Btw, did you try [rxtx](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-java/tree/recipes-extended/rxtx/rxtx_2.2.0.bb) from `meta-java`?

Comment: Hi @Nayfe , I'm not able to modify the yocto toolchain, but I managed somehow to compile this: I forgot $CONFIGURE_FLAGS...